# How to disable Site Isolation in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome 67 has enabled [Site Isolation](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/07/mitigating-spectre-with-site-isolation.html) on Windows, Mac, Linux, and Chrome OS, which increases memory usage by 10-13% and introduces some problems for web developers:

- Full-page multi-frame layout is no longer synchronous, since the frames of a page may be spread across multiple processes,
- `beforeunload` event handlers are not working in cross-site subframes and `unload` event handlers may have issues with `postMessage`,
- DevTools' Network panel does not show cookies and other request headers for cross-site subresource requests.

I want to save RAM more than extra security. How to disable Site Isolation?

Comment: Disabling Site Isolation seems to save more than 10% memory. In my informal testing what would normally be 8 GB of memory use is now 2 GB.

Comment: For me Disabling Site Isolation was the only way to be able to run Chrome without it creating a new background process for every advertisement on every page I visited.  This kept happening until the browser froze.  There were so many ad frames being created for Facebook, GoogleAds, and other advertisement, it was unbearable.  Ad Blockers would not stop the AdFrame processes from getting created either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation), you can disable Site Isolation by adding Chrome command line switch:

```
chrome.exe --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process
```

Another way is to go to `chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out` and select `Opt out`.

In Chrome 68+, you can go to `chrome://process-internals` to verify that Site Isolation is disabled.

Comment: Opting out did not stop the runaway adframes from getting created for me.  Eventually Chrome crashes or hogs so much memory that I have to restart it again and close all tabs for pages that have Facebook (Meta), or other social networking sites that have lots of ads.