# Flask API, browser requests stopped working, no log the request was received

Tags: flask

I have a very simple flask app that has been working for years, but last week requests from the built app return a 500, and from the Flask side, I can't even see the request.  I am not seeing an OPTIONS request.

The below lines worked previously to keep CORS happy.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,Auth-Token')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
    return response
```

I have tried in a few browsers and all of them fail to successfully make any requests. Since the server doesn't even acknowledge the request has been made, I am not sure where to trouble shoot.  I did confirm the app returns data as expected when I use Postman to make the request, as well as confirming that if I use the app locally (gulp serve on my computer) that the requests are successful.  I have to believe its CORS, but what might I have to add / do to get the browser to be happy?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that chrome started to "restrict the ability of websites to communicate with devices on the local network"

[Communicating from Chrome 94+ with LAN devices that do not support HTTPS from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344288/communicating-from-chrome-94-with-lan-devices-that-do-not-support-https-from-a)