# How to savethe webpage as .mht in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How to save the webpage as .mht in puppeteer.

There is an option of taking screenshot, also save as pdf but there is no option to save as HTML or other extensions

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could [set the browser flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607866/setting-specific-chrome-flags-in-puppeteer-enable-and-disable) to enable the saving as [mhtml](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#mhtml-generator-option).
But there is no way to access the browsers context menu to do the save_as.

The easiest option would be to save as PDF and then convert the PDF to MHTML